# Registry key to make word 2003 default on .doc

Tags: microsoft-office

I need to have both word 2003 and word 2010 installed on the same machine.
How can I make word 2003 default on .doc? Registry key?

Tnx

Comment: Uninstall one version of Office? Why do you need 2 versions on the same machine anyway?

Answer (score 2):

You don't set a registry key, you set the default program. Right click any .doc file and you will see a box like below chick change and select Microsoft Word in the Dialog box.

[image]ill

Comment: If another version of Word is running, the document opens in the running version rather than in the associated version.

Comment: I don't think there is a way around that.

Comment: There is a way, I just don't know how it's done.